# C++ Create collection of pointers to objects in two related vector collections

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, collections, polymorphism

I am working in Visual C++ from Visual Studio 2010. I have two collections (vectors) of objects that are similar but not identical. I have created an abstract base class for these two classes that holds all of the common elements.

Each object has, in the base class, a member that holds a sequence number, which is unique and monotonically increasing across the union of the two collections. I need to display these objects to the user, with "Next" and "Previous" buttons, in order by this internal sequence number.

I can't but all of the object in the same collection (for sorting), because they are different classes, even though related. I thought of creating a third collection of pointers to the base class objects and filling it in sorted order for the display. I am having trouble creating this collection (I have tried vector, list, and simple array) and populating it with pointers to the derived class objects in the other two collections.

I am open to any and all suggestions.

Dave

Comment: May be you want us to show the code you actually _"have trouble"_ with (provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27784431/edit) please). So that's the minimum required to get any reasonable help here. (BTW a constant source of _trouble_ is to use raw pointers, instead of [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) for such cases as you describe. Unforunately VS2010 doesn't support this well AFAIK, you should get a newer compiler.)

Answer (score 0):

So your base class should look something like this:

```
class Base{
public:
    Base() : _sequence(s_sequence++){}
    bool operator<(const Base& that) const{return _sequence < that.getSequence();}
    int getSequence() const{return _sequence;}
private:
    int _sequence;
    static int s_sequence;
};

int Base::s_sequence = 0;
```

You can then put everything in a single `std::vector<Base*> foo` which you can sort with the command:

```
std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](Base* first, Base* second){return *first < *second;});
```